# spotipy query does not return resultset from spotify

Tags: spotify, spotipy

I have the following code, but there is an empty response, while the combi title / artist is in spotify.
Is there anybody who can help me?

If i do the same for one of us / abba as track / artist it gives results.

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
import sys
import pprint

artist = 'karel gott'
track = 'eine liebe ist viele tranen wert'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    search_str = sys.argv[1]
else:
    search_str = 'artist:{} track:{}'.format(artist, track)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())
result = sp.search(q=search_str)
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the API will search through songs in the US market, that means songs that can legally only be listened by US customers.

I found that the song you are looking for is available in countries across Europe. For that song I get results in the GB as well as FR markets, and even more results in the german one.

So, just specify the market where you are using Spotify from:

```
sp.search(q=search_str, market="DE")
```

Unfortunately I am not aware of an easy way to search through all markets at once.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Stéphane, that was the solution. I'll keep it in mind  for my spanish songs